# Passing a value by anchor tag through PHP

Tags: php

I do not understand how to use anchor tag to pass a value. I have a form which takes a few values and submits to my mysql database. I am able to view the table. Each row has columns edit and delete. When I click edit I want to pass the primary key(job name) of that row to my edit page and similarly for delete. I am able to see the value on the URL,but I am not able to get the value on the edit page. I do not understand what is the use of ? in anchor tag.

**ViewAllJobs.php**

```
<?php
include 'jobDB.php';
$query="Select * from Jobs";
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
echo'
<html>
<center><h1>View all Jobs</h1></center>
<body bgcolor="#E6E6FA">
<center><form method=POST action=edit.php >
<table border="1" style="border-collapse:collapse; border-color:Black; border-style:solid; border-width:1pt">
<tr>
<th>Job Name</th>
<th>Job State</th>
<th>Schedule days</th>
<th>URL</th>
<th>Filename</th>
<th>To</th>
<th>CC</th>
<th>Reply To</th>
<th>From</th>
<th>EmailSubject</th>
<th>Email Content</th>
<th>Edit</th>
<th>Delete</th>
</tr>';

while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    echo'<tr>
    <td>'.$row["jobName"].' </td>
    <td>'.$row["jobState"].'    </td>
    <td>'.$row["jobSchedule"].' </td>
    <td>'.$row["jobURL"].'  </td>
    <td>'.$row["jobFilename"].' </td>
    <td>'.$row["jobToList"].'   </td>
    <td>'.$row["jobCCList"].'   </td>
    <td>'.$row["jobReplyTo"].'  </td>
    <td>'.$row["jobFrom"].' </td>
    <td>'.$row["jobSubject"].'  </td>
    <td>'.$row["jobEmailContent"].' </td>
    <td><a href="edit.php?jobName='.$row["jobName"].'">Edit</a></td>
    <td><a href="delete.php?jobName='.$row["jobName"].'">Delete</a></td>
    </tr>
    ';
}

echo'</table>
</form>
<center><a href="welcome.php">Click to return to Home Page</a></center>
</center>
</body>

</html>



';
?>
```

**edit.php**

```
<?php
include 'jobDB.php';
$jobName=isset($_REQUEST['jobName']);
if($jobName){
    echo"jobname is set";
}
else{
    echo"job name is not set";
}
echo"<br>jobname is".$jobName;
$query="select* from Jobs where jobName=".$jobName;
$result=mysqli_query($con,$query);
if($result){
    echo"<br>query succesful";

}
$fetch=$row=mysqli_fetch_row($result);
if($fetch){
    echo"<br>result set fetched";
}
else{
        echo"<br>result set not fetched";
    }
?>
```

In edit.php `$jobName=isset($_REQUEST['jobname'])` gives `$jobName=1` when it is supposed to have the value `job1`, but there does not exist a variable `jobname`, when I give `$jobName=isset($_REQUEST['jobName'])`, nothing works. What is the name I should give in `$_REQUEST()`. Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
$jobName = $_REQUEST['jobName'];
```

`isset()` is used to check if variable IS SET, not to assign variables.

When you use `$jobName = isset($_REQUEST['jobName']);`, the variable will be set to `1` as `$_REQUEST['jobName']` is set and `1` represents `true`. Thus `$jobname` becomes `1`.

Your code should be:

```
$jobName = $_REQUEST['jobName'];;
if(isset($jobName)) {
    echo "jobname is set";
}
else {
    echo "job name is not set";
}
echo "<br>jobname is" . $jobName;
$query = "SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE jobName = '$jobName'";
```

To answer what is the use of `?` in anchor tags, it is used for PHP to GET/REQUEST the values, more information at http://www.w3schools.com/php/php_forms.asp.

Hope this helps, thanks!

Comment: did u used anchor tags?

Comment: The anchor tags are set correctly, if the variable is correct.

Comment: I've updated answer to also answer the use of Anchor Tags, thanks anyways :)

Comment: @luweiqi :Thank you so much. $jobName = $_REQUEST['jobName']; solved all the problems.  I also had to write ,$query = "SELECT * FROM Jobs WHERE jobName = '$jobName ' ";